# I trained and saved pytorch model but when load it again in another session with same dataset and test then its accurecy get changes each time

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, model, computer-vision, pytorch-dataloader

I made a FER model  in pytorch and train/test it also on FED-RO dataset with (Accurecy=40 out of 100 test images) and then save it (torch.save) inside another folder in drive by model.pth file. But after loading and test() it gives different accurecy.

```
def test(epoch=None, is_validation=False,pretrained=True):
    model.eval()
    # loader = dataloaders['val'] if is_validation else dataloaders['train']
    test_loss = 0
    test_correct = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for batch_idx, (inputs, targets) in enumerate(dataloaders['val']):
            # print("batch_idx",batch_idx)
            inputs, targets = inputs.to(DEVICE), targets.to(DEVICE)
            outputs = model(inputs)
            # print("outputs",outputs)
            test_loss += F.cross_entropy(outputs, targets, size_average=False).item()
            test_correct+= outputs.max(1)[1].eq(targets).sum().item()
            # print("test_correct",test_correct)
            # test_correct=test_correct+test_correct
    if is_validation:
        writer.add_scalar('logs/val_loss', test_loss/len(datasets['val']), epoch)
        writer.add_scalar('logs/val_acc', test_correct/len(datasets['val']), epoch)
    else:
        print("Test Accuracy: {}/{}".format(test_correct, len(datasets['val'])))
```

I tried different save functions as (torch.save()) or torch.save(model.state_dict(), PATH) but after load model accurecy get changed (86 out of 100 images) each time different accurecy.
I want only that model accurecy should not changed after reloading on different sessions or different files for same datasets.

Comment: How much did the test acc change?

Comment: and how did you load the model?

Comment: Test acc gets changed to double means 40 to 86% after running the Test() function. I load the model using # PATH="/content/drive/MyDrive/trainedmodel/model (1).pth"
# model = torch.load(PATH)
# model.eval()

Comment: [link] (https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1SvyJRWamBpTyzQ5Ep5-OCMzl8qcV5h1K?authuser=9#scrollTo=w8vcSttUxSve)                                                                             Github code link  (https://github.com/PKRaj007/PKRaj007/blob/main/FER_Model_.ipynb)